# Can I display only the first N rows in ReactSelect when I have 1000 items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I use ReactSelect (https://react-select.com/props) to render select boxes. In my specific case, each item rendered in the list of the react select is a "complex" component with CSS and HTML elements:

```
const User = ({ user }) => {
  return (
    <div className="xxxx">
      <b>{user.name}</b>
      // ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I click on the react select to start searching, it displays all my records (2000). It's super slow. Is there a way to limit the number of displayed items to let's say 100?

Side note: the data is frontside so I don't need to call an API.

Comment: just use this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-async-paginate

Comment: Can't you just do `options={your_huge_array.slice(99)}`  since all the data is frontside? (Whether or not it's a good idea for all the data to be frontside is a different discussion)